VisualForce page doesn't display list record from controller
I have a controller to store list from custom object, it shows policy that registered in Contact or not from csv file. But when I store this list in VisualForce, thats not shown anything record. Its different when I store with System.debug and successfully stored in policiesNotValid. This is my code to store records:
public class CallLineRetentionController {
    
    public Blob fileContent {get; set;}
    public String[] fileLines {get; set;}
    public String fileName {get; set;}
    
    public Set<String> policy {get; set;}
    public Set<String> policiesNotValid {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
    public Map<String, Contact> contactMap {get; set;}
        
    public CallLineRetentionController() {
        
        fileLines = new String[]{};
        listClr = new List<Call_Line_Retention__c>();
            
        listClr = [SELECT mdmid_owner__c, Policy_No__c, Remark_Description__c, Retention_Status__c FROM Call_Line_Retention__c];
        
    }

public PageReference uploadFile() {
        
        fileName = fileContent.toString();
        fileLines = fileName.split('\n');
                
        try {
            policy = new Set<String>();
            contactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
            for (Integer i = 1; i < fileLines.size(); i++) {
                String[] record = fileLines[i].split(',');
                String policyNo = record[0].trim();
                
                if (!String.isBlank(policyNo)) {
                    policy.add(policyNo);
                }
            }
                       
            policiesNotValid = new Set<String>();
            for (String policyNo : policy) {
                if (!contactMap.containsKey(policyNo)) {
                    policiesNotValid.add(policyNo);
                }
            }
            System.debug('not valid : '+policiesNotValid);
            
            if (contacts.isEmpty() || contactMap.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            
            parseCsvRecords(fileLines, contactMap, listClr);
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ApexPages.Message errorMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMsg);
        }
            
        upsert listClr;
        
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CallLineRetentionLayout?upload=success&uploadedNum='+uploadedNum+'&validNum='+validNum+'&invalidNum='+invalidNum);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }



and I have called the list on the Visualforce page:
<apex:page controller="CallLineRetentionController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="" subtitle="Call Line Retention"/>
    <apex:form id="formCallLine">  
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Policy List">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listClr}" var="list" style="overflow:auto;width:850px;" border="1">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Policy No" value="{!list.Policy_No__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Remark Description" value="{!list.Remark_Description__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Retention Status" value="{!list.Retention_Status__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <br/>
<!--this list is not shows-->
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Policy has not been registered in Contact">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!policiesNotValid}" var="sets" style="width:250px;" border="1">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Policy No" value="{!sets}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    </div>
</apex:page>

Can anyone provide an explanation, why the list of variables policiesNotValid cannot appear on the Visualforce page?
Sorry if there are any shortcomings, because I'm new to using this platform

pageRef.setRedirect(true); resets the view state, so the values you set in uploadFile are lost. In order to keep the values, don't redirect with this flag. In fact, you don't need to redirect at all. It is perfectly fine to use void as the return type for an action function where you want to perform some action and then update the state of the page.
public void uploadFile() {
    fileName = fileContent.toString();
    fileLines = fileName.split('\n');
    try {
        policy = new Set<String>();
        contactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
        for (Integer i = 1; i < fileLines.size(); i++) {
            String[] record = fileLines[i].split(',');
            String policyNo = record[0].trim();
            
            if (!String.isBlank(policyNo)) {
                policy.add(policyNo);
            }
        }
        policiesNotValid = new Set<String>();
        for (String policyNo : policy) {
            if (!contactMap.containsKey(policyNo)) {
                policiesNotValid.add(policyNo);
            }
        }
        System.debug('not valid : '+policiesNotValid);
        if (contacts.isEmpty() || contactMap.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        parseCsvRecords(fileLines, contactMap, listClr);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.Message errorMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured');
        ApexPages.addMessage(errorMsg);
    }
    upsert listClr;
    // void return needs no return statement at the end
}

Note that I advise against parsing a CSV this way, because you're not properly parsing the CSV file. There are lots of examples out there of how to properly parse a CSV file in Apex.
